# How to restore a database to the SQL Database service in Bluemix?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-cloud

We have a full backup of an SQL database and we want to restore that to an instance of the SQL Database service in Bluemix. Could you please advise how to restore a database to that service?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? SQL Server? Or another one? Your tags are not clear.

Comment: we have used sql server DBMS.

Comment: Just as a comment for other people viewing this question, the SQL Database service in Bluemix is not running MS SQL server, it runs on top of DB2.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the SQL Database console for restore/backup function.  The console provides the ability to perform the following functions:

- Create and drop objects, view object details, browse and export data.
- Load the data from your data source into a database table for the cloud
- Backup the data for the cloud database to store it in a different location
- Restore the data to the cloud database from a different location
- View the applications that are connected to a database
- View data privacy records
- View SQL statements for a database
- View the list of table spaces and their status

For more details, please see the link below:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SQLDB/index.html#sqldb_005